# In AWS Cloudfront, how to invalidate the home page only?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

How to invalidate only the  home page (https://mywebsite/) from cloudfront? Usually subsequest path, then we would  say `images/image1.png` or `/images/*`. But if it is the home page, when how do we mention the object path?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to invalidate *only* the home page, when the home page is requested like http://example.com or https://example.com/ (etc.) (If it is requested like http://example.com/index.htm it can be invalidated using an invalidation path of `/index.htm`)

I have had this confirmed by Amazon via a support case where I asked this specific question. They confirmed, the only way to invalidate the home page, when requested like http://example.com or https://example.com/ (etc.), is to invalidate the whole distribution/site using an invalidation path of `/*` (Trying an invalidation path of `/` has no effect.)

The good news is that an invalidation path of `/*` only counts as one path, so the cost of using it (if one has gone above the free allowance of 1,000 paths each month) is only the same as a more specific path like `/index.htm` for example.